# Change background color for div

Tags: css, html, hover

The code that I currently have is this:

```
.button2 {
margin-left: 10px;
background-color: lightgreen;
width: 180px;
height:100px;
padding: 50px,60px;
color: rgba(20, 15, 30, 0.8);
text-transform: uppercase;
border: 1px solid green ;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;    
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-border-radius: 3px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 0 -1px 0 rgba(25, 27, 9, 0.9);     
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 5px 0 #3a79a4, 0 6px 0 #593a11, 0 13px 0 #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 5px 0 #3a79a4, 0 6px 0 #593a11, 0 13px 0 #ccc;
-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 5px 0 #3a79a4, 0 6px 0 #593a11, 0 13px 0 #ccc;
-webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-out;

.button2:hover {
background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

The problem, however, is that whenever I hover my mouse over the div, the background color of the box does not change to red.

How can I make it so that whenever I hover over divs with class button2 it will change to the background color red? Is there a problem with the formatting?

My current HTML is:

```
<html>
<div class=button2></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a link...the :hover seems be ok...should be something more

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple user error which is not likely to help others in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple syntax error - you forgot to close `.button2 {}`

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KMqjX/) - it works now

**Updated CSS**

```
.button2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px,60px;
    color: rgba(20, 15, 30, 0.8);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid green;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 0 -1px 0 rgba(25, 27, 9, 0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 5px 0 #3a79a4, 0 6px 0 #593a11, 0 13px 0 #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 5px 0 #3a79a4, 0 6px 0 #593a11, 0 13px 0 #ccc;
    -box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 5px 0 #3a79a4, 0 6px 0 #593a11, 0 13px 0 #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
}

.button2:hover {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

As a side note, it's always helpful to view these errors in the F12 dev tool.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it had something to do with the syntax. Syntax can be annoying sometimes.